# Powershell: Add-Type - Permission denied

Tags: powershell, permissions, add-type

i ran into an issue while using this code to include some local dll.

Add-Type -Path "c:\temp\some.dll"

This will work on some machine and fail on some machines.
All of those have been installed with the same W10 image, they also use the same policies.
All have unrestricted Execution Policies and the same Powershell Version 5.1.
There is no difference between 32 and 64-bit machines.
Affected devices will throw a "permission denied" error and we have switched dll files and path and made sure we have access rights and the ISE is running as admin.
Additionally i have checked that all machines are using the same .Net version.
On working machines the Type will be added without error.

I tried to "break" my config so i will get the same error but was not successful yet.
As i am running out of ideas i would appreciate very much any hint on where to search next or what to test.
Thank you all in advance !

Comment: Please post the error messages _in its entirety_.

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\some.dll"
Add-Type : Der Typ kann nicht hinzugefügt werden. Die Definition neuer Typen wird in diesem 
Sprachmodus nicht unterstützt.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\some.dll ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Add-Type], PSNotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotDefineNewType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

Comment: "Sprachmodus" = "Language Mode". My first guess is that an administrator enabled AppLocker or similar application control policies on the affected machines.

Comment: to make things even stranger $ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode will show FullLanguage

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

We have found out that, on affected machines, a hidden value was used to set the LanguageMode to Restricted.
`$__PSLockDownPolicy` was set to 4 in the system environment parameters. Change that to 8 and the permission denials are gone.